# Deleting locally created user after WDS Deployment

Tags: windows-server-2008, deployment, wds, answer-file

I'm pushing out a new Win7 image to several machines using WDS, unattend.xml, and oobeunattend.xml.

Naturally you have to create the local user in the OOBE experience but it isn't something I want to keep there.

I added this to my OOBE.xml but it isn't working, its even after my domain joining component:

```
<settings pass="auditUser">
- <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 - <RunSynchronous>
   - <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
      - <Credentials>
           <Domain>DOMAIN</Domain> 
           <Password>PASSWORD</Password> 
           <Username>administrator</Username> 
        </Credentials>
        <Order>1</Order> 
        <Description>Removes original test user</Description> 
        <Path>net user temp /del</Path> 
      </RunSynchronousCommand>
    </RunSynchronous>
  </component>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo I got it!

In my answer file, instead of doing a script (which was running in the Specialize component anyway, and the user was created in oobeSystem) in specialize, I added `Windows-Shell-Setup --> FirstLogonCommands` and put the command there.  Worked perfectly!  Thanks!